# The property 'IsHandWritingViewEnabled' was not found in type 'TextBox'

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, handwriting-recognition

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/text-handwriting-view), the WPF TextBox has a property named "IsHandwritingViewEnabled".

I want to use the WPF TextBox in a container in a VB6 app.

To do that, I create a new project with type "WPF Browser User Control Library (.NET Framework):

[image]

It automatically adds a UserControl.

I drag a WPF TextBox onto this UserControl:

[image]

To test if the property can be accessed, I add

```
IsHandwritingViewEnabled="True"
```

to the textbox. However, this does not work. It says "The property 'IsHandWritingViewEnabled' was not found in type 'TextBox'.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't that for UWP apps?

Comment: @Jimi You were right. This property is only accessible if I use a UWP project template. Can you add this answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)  in wpf does not have the 'IsHandWritingViewEnabled' property.  'IsHandWritingViewEnabled' property is for UWP TextBox.